# MPI_Scatter: order of scatter

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I my work, I noticed that even if I scatter same amount of data to each process, it takes more time to transfer data from root to the highest-rank process. I tested this on distributed memory machine. If a MWE is needed I will prepare one but before that I would like to know if MPI_Scatter gives privilege to lower rank processes.

Comment: If the standard doesn't say so you shouldn't rely on it. Intuitively I wouldn't think this to be the case. I'd expect scatter to send all data in a tree-esque fashion (or in some special / hardware accelerated way depending on the underlying hardware) to all ranks.

Comment: 99.9% sure it's entirely implementation defined and may very well differ for OpenMPI based on configuration. Is there a practical question behind this? Generally you are talking about different nodes with different clocks, so there's no well-defined global order anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The MPI standard does not say such a thing, so MPI libraries are free to implement `MPI_Scatter()` the way they want regarding which task might return earlier than others.

`Open MPI` for example can either do a linear or a binomial scatter (by default, the algo is chosen based on communicator and message sizes).

That being said, all data has to be sent from the root process to the other nodes, so obviously, some nodes will be served first. If root process has rank zero, i would expect the highest rank process receive the data at last (i am not aware of any MPI library implementing a topology aware `MPI_Scatter()`, but that might come some day). If root process has not rank zero, then MPI might internally renumber the ranks (so root is always virtual rank zero), and if this pattern is implemented, the last process to receive the data would be `(root + size - 1) % size`.

If this is suboptimal from your application point of view, you always have the option to re-implement `MPI_Scatter()` your own way (that can call the library provided `PMPI_Scatter()` if needed). An other approach would be to `MPI_Comm_split()` (with a single color) in order to renumber the ranks, and use the new communicator for `MPI_Scatter()`